# R Shiny Plotly generate graph for each item in list

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Right now I'm using shiny and Plotly in R to make graphs to visualize data.

I have this list with items and for each item I want to generate a graph with the name of this item.

Is it possible to have your graph output name based on this list item?

**In the simplest terms:**

What I have:

```
output$plot <- renderPlotly({})
```

What I want:

```
listitems <- c("graph1", "graph2")

output$listitems[1] <- renderPlotly({})
```

This situation would be ideal, as I want to generate multiple graphs by using a function to minimalize code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to assign every plot manually. Accordingly we can use a `for-loop` or `lapply` like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("myPlots")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  listItems <- paste0("graph", 1:10)
  dfList <- replicate(10, data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10)), simplify = FALSE)
  names(dfList) <- listItems

  lapply(seq_along(dfList), function(i){
    output[[listItems[i]]] <- renderPlotly({plot_ly(dfList[[i]], x = ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers") %>% layout(title = listItems[i])})
  })

  output$myPlots <- renderUI({
    lapply(listItems, plotlyOutput)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [subplots](https://plot.ly/r/subplots/). In your example, this would have to be something like:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
    plotlyOutput("plot")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  p1 <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~unemploy) %>%
     add_lines(name = ~"unemploy")
  p2 <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~uempmed) %>%
    add_lines(name = ~"uempmed")

  listitems <- list(p1, p2)

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({

   subplot(listitems)

    })
   }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Output:

[image]