# Generating sets of graphics and tables in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to display summary tables and graphics for a couple dozen variables in a shiny app.

Currently on the server I have code like this:

```
  # Smoking ----
  ### is_smoker_table1 -----
  output$is_smoker_table1 <- renderTable(
    make_table1(is_smoker, `History of Smoking`)
  )

  ### is_smoker_ggplot -----
  output$is_smoker_ggplot <- renderPlot(
    make_gg_bar(is_smoker, `History of Smoking`)
  )

  ### per_day_table1 -----
  output$per_day_table1 <- renderTable(
    make_table1(per_day, `Cigarettes per day`)
  )

  ### per_day_ggplot -----
  output$per_day_ggplot <- renderPlot(
    make_gg_bar(per_day, `Cigarettes per day`)
  )
```

In the GUI I have code like this:

```
          ## Smoking ----
          tabPanel(
            "Smoking",
            fluidRow(
              box( ### is_smoker ----
                width = 12, title = "Smoking Status",
                tableOutput("is_smoker_table1"),
                plotOutput("is_smoker_ggplot")
              )
            ),
            fluidRow(
              box(### per_day ----
                width = 12, title = "Cigarettes per day",
                tableOutput("per_day_table1"),
                plotOutput("per_day_ggplot")
              )
            )
          ),
```

I hate the idea of doing the copy and paste thing a couple dozen times.

I saw a useful [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933135/r-shiny-plotly-generate-graph-for-each-item-in-list) which uses `lapply()` to generate all the server objects and then print them all in a series.

I think eventually  code like this will work:

```
the_summary <- function(old_name, new_name) {
  
  the_table1 <- renderTable(
    make_table1(old_name, new_name)
  )
  
  the_ggplot <- renderPlot(
    make_gg_bar(old_name, new_name)
  )
  
  list(the_table1 = the_table1, the_ggplot = the_ggplot)
}

#extract the table
output$is_smoker_table1 <- the_summary(is_smoker, `History of Smoking`)[[1]]

#extract the graphic 
output$is_smoker_ggplot <- the_summary(is_smoker, `History of Smoking`)[[2]]
```

But that is only marginally better. My `map()` and `lapply()` skills are weak so I don't see how to do this efficiently.

Is there a straight forward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example storing each `output` id and their placeholder in lists that can be rendered with `lapply`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("uiElements")
 )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
#The first list will be used to render the uiElements of the app:
  itemsUI <- list(title = c("Smoking Status", "Cigarettes per day"),
       tableOutputId = c("is_smoker_table1", "per_day_table1"),
       plotOutputId = c("is_smoker_ggplot", "per_day_ggplot"))
  
 output$uiElements <- renderUI({
   tabPanel(
    "Smoking",
    lapply(1:length(itemsUI[[1]]), 
           function(i) {
             fluidRow(
               box( ### is_smoker ----
                    width = 12, title = itemsUI$title[[i]],
                    tableOutput(itemsUI$tableOutputId[[i]]),
                    plotOutput(itemsUI$plotOutputId[[i]]))
               ) 
           }
           )
    )
 })

 #The second list will be used to render the outputs:
 table1 = mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl)
 table2 = mtcars %>% select(disp, hp)
 
 plot1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point()
 plot2 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, hp)) + geom_point()
 
 itemsOutput <- list(
   tables = list(table1, table2),
   plots = list(plot1, plot2))
 
 
 lapply(1:length(itemsOutput$tables), function(i){
   output[[itemsUI$tableOutputId[i]]] <- renderTable({itemsOutput$tables[[i]]})
   output[[itemsUI$plotOutputId[i]]] <- renderPlot({itemsOutput$plots[[i]]})
 })
  
  
}
```